# CAML Query using "Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'" returns no results

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml, splist

I have the following CAML query to programmatically filter a list:

`<Query>
    <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq><FieldRef Name='notificationExpires' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2011-03-30T00:00:00Z</Value></Geq> 
         <Or>
            <Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'><FieldRef Name='notificationTargetRoles'/></Membership>
            <Contains><FieldRef Name='notificationTargetRoles'/><Value Type='User'>MyDomain\administrator</Value></Contains>
         </Or>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>`

When I execute this exact same query (running under the same account) in the U2U CAML Query Builder I get filtered users, groups and dates.
When apply exact the same filter in code, the Groups do not appear in the results.

What can be the reason that the group filter (CurrentGroups) does not return any results?

The code for applying the filter is:

```
 SPListItemCollection items = null;
         SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
         {
             using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(theSiteName))
             {
                 using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                 {
                     SPList alertList = elevatedWeb.Lists[theListName];
                     SPQuery query = new SPQuery();


                     query.Query = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='notificationExpires' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2011-03-30T00:00:00Z</Value></Geq> <Or><Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'><FieldRef Name='notificationTargetRoles'/></Membership><Contains><FieldRef Name='notificationTargetRoles'/><Value Type='User'>BSFLMK\administrator</Value></Contains></Or></And></Where>";

                     items = alertList.GetItems(query);
                 }
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that removing the  "`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()`" part corrected the problem

Comment: Indeed, in case of elevated site, the security context is that of System Account